# Magento 2: How to create custom grid report based on Order collection?

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, grid, uicomponent

I want to create a new report showed as an option at

```
Reports -> Sales -> My New Report
```

This new report should be based on the Orders collection joined to other existing Magento core tables, as well as applying some filters (the columns should be different than the Orders report).

Any idea of how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

I have been able to add it to the menu as shown in the image:

[image]

But when clicking on the page, it shows just the blank page with the title (as expected as I don't have the `uiComponent`)